# print the same level of xml data with a condition in python

Tags: python, xml

I have an xml file. I didn't make this file so I don't want to make any changes. I want to print the screen by pulling the information that provides certain conditions from the file. The value I want to get is on the same level as the value I'll do with the comparison. So even if I can check the condition, I can't pull the other data. How can I do this?

asd.xml

```
<report>
    <name>asd</name>
    <description>example description - 1</description>
</report>
<report>
    <name>dsa</name>
    <description>example description - 2</description>
</report>
<report>
    <name>asd</name>
    <description>example description - 3</description>
</report>
```

asd.py

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('asd.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for report_1 in root:
    for report_2 in report_1:
        if result.tag == 'name':
            if result.text == 'asd':
                print ?
```

I find the ones that are equal to asd by retrieving the value from tag name "name". but I cannot access the same level decription value.

I want output

```
name: asd
description: example description - 1
name: asd
description: example description - 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file produces an error:

> ParseError: junk after document element: line 5, column 0

Should it look like this:

```
<data>
    <report>
        <name>asd</name>
        <description>example description - 1</description>
    </report>
    <report>
        <name>dsa</name>
        <description>example description - 2</description>
    </report>
    <report>
        <name>asd</name>
        <description>example description - 3</description>
    </report>
</data>
```

You could use the following code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('asd.xml')

root = tree.getroot()

flag = False

for report in root:
    flag = False
    for row in report:
        if row.tag == 'name' and row.text == 'asd':
            print('name: asd')
            flag = True
        if flag and row.tag == 'description':
            print('description: {}'.format(row.text))
```

That would provide you with desired result:

```
name: asd
description: example description - 1
name: asd
description: example description - 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

**asd.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <report>
        <name>asd</name>
        <description>example description - 1</description>
    </report>
    <report>
        <name>dsa</name>
        <description>example description - 2</description>
    </report>
    <report>
        <name>asd</name>
        <description>example description - 3</description>
    </report>
</root>
```

**Python3**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(r"asd.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

for report in root:
    if report.find('name').text == "asd":
        print("name: ", report.find('name').text)
        print("description: ", report.find('description').text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use the XPath query to get the correct output.

asd.xml

```
<data>
  <report>
    <name>asd</name>
    <description>example description - 1</description>
  </report>
  <report>
    <name>dsa</name>
    <description>example description - 2</description>
  </report>
  <report>
    <name>asd</name>
    <description>example description - 3</description>
  </report>
</data>
```

Now, If we use this query mentioned below will get your expected output.

```
'./report[name ="asd"]/description'
```

```pyton
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse('asd.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
print(root)
for key in root.findall('./report[name ="asd"]/description'):
    print(key.tag, key.text)
```

Result:

```
<Element 'data' at 0x0000020D4865CEF8>
description example description - 1
description example description - 3
```